# Remove head part from loading

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to load a page from a click on product thumbnail. I'm using this

```
     $(".kategorie").click(function(){
    var post_id = $(this).attr("href");

    $("#categories_box").load(post_id);
return false;
});
```

However It loads the whole website, I mean the header part as well, I don't think it is a good thing ;) Also after loading a page few times, I'm receiving jquery error "undefined is not a function " . I think it's cuz of that double header part, Can I stop loading header somehow ? Or the problem is different that I think ? ;)

If I didn't explain it well, please ask me a question. Here's the website http://usb-solutions.pl/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a jquery selector to you `.load`. just add a space between the url and the selector :

```
$("#categories_box").load(post_id + " body");//Will get only the body
```

Comment: Thanks for quick reply, now I cant see any errors, but as well i cant see the data. It loads nothing ;(

Comment: Okey, after going further with your suggestion I just added + " #page" which was my id container , and it works ;) thank you

Comment: @MateuszWinnicki somehow, load strip the <body> tag out of the HTML. Change it to, for example `#page` and it work.

Comment: Yea, however now I faced another problem ,after loading a product, my image slider stopped working ;(

Comment: @MateuszWinnicki Which slider? Where?

Comment: Thumbnails slider, On the right box where are product details there are thumbnails, as a carousell.

Comment: @MateuszWinnicki Your javascript need to be *"rerun"*. I suggest you use `.ajax` and run a function on complete.... It's far more complicated than your original question and don't exactly have the time to answer that. Sorry...

Answer (score 0):

you can simply write below code

```
$("#categories_box").load(post_id + " body");
```

Comment: Thanks for quick reply, now I cant see any errors, but as well i cant see the data. It loads nothing ;(